# Request for non-Einstein positive constant scalar curvature Kähler surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

I am curious about concrete examples of compact cscK manifolds in complex dimension two, in particular cscK surfaces with positive scalar curvature.

There are of course the Fano (del Pezzo) Kähler-Einstein surfaces, all of which are obtained by blowing up $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ at finitely many distinct points, or $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb C\mathbb P^1$. In fact, $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1 \times C$ where $C$ is a compact Riemann surface admits cscK metrics of any sign by taking product metrics. *What are some other examples of non-KE positive cscK surfaces?*

*I would be particularly interested in examples which have holomorphic vector fields* since for example, by a result of [Lebrun-Simanca](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02926444), any scalar flat but not Ricci flat Kähler surface with no holomorphic vector fields also admits a positive cscK metric. Once one has a positive cscK surface with no holomorphic vector fields, one can apply results of [Arezzo-Pacard](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411522) to get a positive cscK metric on the blow up of any finite set of points.

Note that the existence of a positive cscK metric would imply that the surface has Kodaira dimension $-\infty$ (for a proof see the paper by Lebrun-Simanca linked above). Thus by the Kodaira-Enriques classification any such surface would be obtained by a sequence of blowups of $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ or a geometrically ruled surface (a holomorphic $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ bundle over a compact Riemann surface, or equivalently the projectivization of any rank 2 holomorphic vector bundle on a compact Riemann surface). Any ideas on how to construct the requested examples or direction to a resource containing such examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately am not able to comment, so I’ll have to write what I can say here: As you point out, the compact surfaces admitting Kähler metrics of positive Ricci curvature, i.e., Del Pezzo surfaces, are given by the blow-up of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at $0 \leq k \leq 8$ points in general position. The existence of a Kähler metric with positive scalar curvature implies that the Kodaira dimension is negative, and hence, they are either Del Pezzo surfaces or Hirzebruch surfaces. In fact, the existence of a Hermitian metric with positive Chern scalar curvature implies that the Kodaira dimension is negative by an elementary Bochner argument. Hitchin showed that all Hirzebruch surfaces admit Kähler (in fact, Hodge) metrics of positive holomorphic sectional curvature, and thus, have positive scalar curvature.

The blow-up of $\mathbf{P}^2$ admits a conformally Kähler metric that is Einstein, this is due to Page. Chen—LeBrun—Weber constructed a conformally Kähler Hermitian metric on the blow-up of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at two points. These are not Kähler—Einstein, since their automorphism groups are not reductive. Further, there are no constant scalar curvature metrics on these examples (see, [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95647/a-question-about-the-existence-of-a-constant-scalar-curvature-metric-on-mathbb?rq=1) for additional details). This 2013 paper of [Otoba](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7241.pdf) seems to construct conformally Kähler metrics of constant scalar curvature on Hirzebruch surfaces. I have not read the paper, so I cannot comment further. I hope this is at least somewhat helpful.